# Why CORS still not works in WebAPI?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cross-domain, cors, angular-http

I tried to set everything in web config and I see correct response headers for OPTIONS request made by browser, but why it is still not allowed? I am trying to use WebAPI post requests with AngularJS 1.2.

[image]

Comment: Is it a *POST* WebAPI method?

Comment: Yes, when I run that method on same domain, everything works.

Comment: What does the error message say?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

> Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Content-Type
>
> Accept Access-Control-Allow-Methods:DELETE, PUT, POST, GET
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*